# Can I run Akeneo on a Rasperbby Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, akeneo

I am trying out Akeneo (Product Information Management). It can run under Ubuntu.
Is it possible to run Akeneo (www.akeneo.com) on a Raspberry Pi?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's totally doable and in fact I already did it.